# How can I use jQuery to add a fade in hover effect to my nav items?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, fadein, background-position

I'm brand new to jQuery (and JS in general) and I know it is possible to use it to add a fade in effect to my navigation rollovers.

Right now I'm using a master background sprite for the nav, and on :hover I'm just adding a background-position rule to shift the sprite down for each item to get my hover effect.

But I'd like to use jQuery to bring a smooth transition to the rollover effect. I googled it and found some similiar info, but mostly what I found dealt with instances where you have two images and fading one out to reveal the other. But I'm using CSS background-position to simply shift the image down. Can I do this more smoothe with jQuery, and how?

Here's the site:  http://tuscaroratackle.com

Comment: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/

Comment: That article - while helpful - heals more with animating the background image, whereas I'm trying to get it to fadein/fadeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 example from 100-Th

Add in

tag a  element , and apply from CSS background style class  for the "span.bg1" and "a:hover span.bg2 (when it is :hover)"

```
 <li class="nav-link " id="rods">
      <a href="/rods">
      <span class="bg1">Rods</span>
      <span class="bg2" style="display:none;">Rods</span>
      </a>

  </li>
```

jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#nav li").each(function(){
        $(this).mouseover(function(){


                $(this).find("a span.bg1").fadeOut() ;
                $(this).find("a span.bg2").fadein() ;


        });

    });

});



 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul#nav li").each(function(){
        $(this).mouseover(function(){


                $(this).find("a").addClass("bg1").fadeOut() ;
                $(this).find("a").fadeIn();


        });

    });

});
```

and the same thing when mouse is out to change back background, it is not a code ready to use, it even wasn't tested , but it is for an idea for you

instead fade you can use any effect !

P.S. : But I think just :hover effect is  more user friendly and doesn't look bad :)

Comment: Nice - but is there a way to do it without adding the extra spans into the markup? I'd prefer not to duplicate the markup if possible for a gracefully degrading experience to non-js or even non-css users.

Comment: yup,

change gust the class, and apply fadeIn and fadeOut

Comment: I saved for you another example , you can add some delay for fading effect

Comment: OK, I'm almost there I think. That kinda worked - except if you look at it right now you'll see what happens is the effect appears, then fades in and out, instead of just fading in on hover.